# Applying one color to many layers in QGIS 3?

Tags: layers, symbology, qgis-3, color

I've been playing around with my QGIS Bonn (3.2.3) and I have a question regarding styles/symbology/colours.

Is it possible in QGIS to set one colour/style to multiple layers at once?

Comment: Save as `QML` or `SLD` through `Properties -> Style -> Save` and `Load` or simply `Style -> Copy Style -> Paste Style`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In QGIS 3.6, right-click the layer that you want keep its style `-> Styles -> Copy style -> Select Symbology`

[image]

Then go to other layer select them all using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and left-click on your mouse, then right-click any place above the selected layer `-> Paste Style`

[image]

All of them will have the same style:

[image]