# Clipped Layers Lose Saved Style

Tags: qgis, clip, style-manager

I have a QGIS 3.12 project which covers a large area and has 25 layers of different types.  Each layer has its own saved style.
Occasionally I am required to create a "sub-project" which forms a smaller area of the large project.  After creating the clipping polygon to define the boundaries of the smaller project, I use the Clip Multiple Layers plugin to create 25 clipped layers which come into existence with some type of default styling.  Is there some way to avoid the time-consuming task of applying the saved styles individually to each of the 25 clipped layers?

Comment: You can copy the style and paste it to all selected layers at once. Check [Applying one color to many layers in QGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/314399/63384)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ten days ago I sent a pull request to the https://github.com/Taknok/Qgisplugin-ClipMultipleLayers repo on GitHub with some enhancement and the request was accepted and on 14th of March a new version was released which contains my improvements. In the 3.1.0 version there is a **Save vector styles** (qml) option.

[image]

If you select **Save vector styles** option a .qml file will be save for each  layers with the same name and into the same folder. The styles from this file will be applied when you open the clipped layer in QGIS.

Comment: Great solution, but unfortunately when I try to upgrade the ClipMultipleLayers plugin, I get error message "Couldn't load plugin 'ClipMultipleLayers' due to an error when calling its classfactory() method"

Comment: I've just installed from the Plugin manager and it works without any issue. Which QGIS version do you use?

Comment: Re-installed plugin successfully, ran plugin, perfect result.  Full marks to developer for saving me so much work.

Comment: @Bil C Please accept my answer.